# Console C# application launching a Web browser at startup

Tags: c#

I have created a console application project that references a web service.
For some reason what I write in the code is ignored and the application launches a browser window.

I replaced all the content of the class with this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AXApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ABC");
            var abc = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And I still have the same problem.
It has never happened to me before.
What's wrong?

Comment: Please provide the code that does what you intent but that doesn't work as expected

Comment: Are you saying that the code above (write/read the console) starts a web browser?! Perhaps you've got several projects and it's an other that is started up by F5? Can you set up a break point and see if it's hit during the execution?

Comment: It'll be a program of the century, if you say the above code starts a web browser!!

Comment: Now, let's talk about your original problem - the ignored code part. Is that resolved now as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm **guessing** that you've got several projects in your solution and the one listed is not the one that is executed when you <kbd>F5</kbd> it.

I suggest that you set up a break point and see if it's hit during the execution. My bet it isn't.

Try go right-mouse on the project listed and select *Set as start up project*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am blindly guessing that you have your referenced web service as a start-up project, because actually running the service would open a browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Are you starting this program from .exe file or you just debugging it form VS (F5) ?

Try to start it from executable, if the browser will not show up, then in VS check Console Project -> Properties -> Debug -> Start Action and check if you have "Start browser with URL" option enabled.